# Why fgets and gets are not working to read strings into a struct?

Tags: c, struct

My code to read a string into a struct isn't working. I've tried fgets, gets and also scanf, and none of them is working, returning random characters when I run the code. Can anyonye please help me? Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char string[100];
};

struct student get_detail(int n)
{
    struct student wannabe;
    if (n==1)
    {
        printf("String:\n");
        scanf("%s", wannabe.string);
        //fgets(wannabe.string, 100, stdin) didn't work;
        //gets (wannabe.string) also didn't work
        //scanf("%s", wannabe.string) didn't work
        return wannabe;
    }
}
void main()
{
    int x = 1;
    struct student test = get_detail(x);
    printf("\nString:%s", test.string);

}
```

Comment: `get_detail` isn't returning anything, so your function has *undefined behavior*

Comment: Sorry, when reducing the code to post here I've deleted the return part.  I will edit the post. It isn't working it it also.

Comment: Your function still doesn't `return` anything when `n` is not 1. Though on IDEOne this code still works: https://ideone.com/R7VlHW

Comment: Just debugged your code in VS 2017, it works perfect as it is. However, you should think about what to return when `n != 1`, and read some input at the end of your `main` so that it doesn't exit immediately.

Comment: Change return type of `main` to `int`. Your code works for me as you posted it, after fixing to `int main()` and adding `return wannabe;` before closing `}` inside `get_detail`.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed in the latest version(s) of C.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", wannabe.string);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the input format conversion specifier: `%s`  and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input,  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  note: `%s` will stops inputting when it encounters any `white space` character.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%99s", wannabe.string) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input string\n" );`  You might want to look at: `scanf("%99[^\n]", wannabe.string);`  as that will input until a newline is encountered or 99 characters are input, which ever comes first

Comment: `fgets()` leaves a trailing `'\n'`  (assuming input from the user is not longer than the buffer).  `scanf("%s",...)` does not.

Comment: `printf("\nString:%s", test.string);` --> `printf("\nString:<%s>\n", test.string);`  (Flush the output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Kamil Cuk is right:
Change return type of main to int. Your code works for me as you posted it, after fixing to int main() and adding return wannabe; before closing } inside get_detail

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student 
{
    char string[100];
};

struct student get_detail(int n)
{
    struct student wannabe;
    char ch;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        printf("String:\n");
        fgets(wannabe.string, 100, stdin);
        strtok(wannabe.string, "\n");
        if (strlen(wannabe.string) == 100 - 1) 
        {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); // getchar() in loop to clean stdin
        }
        wannabe.string[strcspn(wannabe.string, "\n")] = 0; // to remove '\n' if the user does not type anything
    }

    return wannabe;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    struct student test = get_detail(x);
    printf("\nString: %s\n", test.string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't speak english yet and i'm new here

Comment: `strtok(wannabe.string, "\n");` fails to remove the `'\n'` when buffer is `"\n"`.  It will if other characters read.  Not a uniform way of removing `'\n'`.

Comment: strtok removes '\n' from string and not from buffer. The '\n' is removed from the buffer with the getchar command.
I recommend debugging the code or entering the scanf ("%*c") command before wannabe is returned

Comment: Limit string length to 6 and type "hello baby" leaving scanf as I said. Result: "hello\0"

Comment: "strtok removes '\n' from string" --> it does not  when `'\n'` is first.  Try `char s[] = "\n";
  strtok(s, "\n");
  printf("<%s>\n", s);` to see that.

Comment: Let's look at the return of the strtok function: `char s[] = "\n";`  `char *token;`  `token = strtok(s, "\n");`  `printf("<%s>", token);`

Comment: Now `'\n'` not being the first: `char s[] = "abc\n";` `char *token = NULL;`
`token = strtok(s, "\n");` `printf("<%s>", token);`

Comment: Posted code does not use the return value of `strtok()`, so the 2 examples do not directly apply.  Code uses `strtok(wannabe.string, "\n");` and later `return wannabe;`.  Thus the calling code can print `"\nString: \n\n"`. Certainly an unexpected output.  Good alternative: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359)

Comment: Now it's clear that the issue is that you didn't like my code. Nothing against. I see it as something personal

Comment: Nothing personal.  It is simple that the code removes the `'\n'` in many cases, yet not in the case of user input beginning with `'\n'`.

Comment: I followed your recommendation: I edited the code. Thanks!